# Can a client side certificate be sent along in a header?

Tags: curl, request, http-headers, certificate

From a MS IIS server I need to request some files. I can do that manually using curl like this:

```
curl --cert thecert.pem --http1.1 -i https://somehost.com/somefile.pdf
```

As you can see I manually provide a client side certificate along with the request. I now need to be able to do this request from the [Cantaloupe image server](https://github.com/cantaloupe-project/cantaloupe) but I can't find any option to do this in [the documentation](https://cantaloupe-project.github.io/). I can however, provide headers along with the request. I don't really have experience with client side certificates, but as far as I know they cannot be placed in the header of a request.

But before I dive into the sources of Cantaloupe to make a fork and fight with Java I want to be sure that I'm right in my thinking.

Can client side certificates be defined in a request header? Or am I right in thinking that that is not possible?

Answer (score 0):

Certificates, may it be from file or from crypto device like usb token or smartcard, can be encoded in Base64 string.  Thus it is possible to provide certificates in request header in Base64 encoded format.

Comment: But I suppose this would require an adjustment on in the IIS server to get the cert from the header right? Plus, as far as I know, headers are sent in plaintext, which would make the whole setup really insecure. Right?

Comment: In your line of code you have referred to pdf file.  What exactly you want to achieve? If it is web application api, you can handle header received in that application.  Regarding security of header, its encrypted if site or api or channel is SSL or TLS i.e. HTTPS